# What does "their own properties" refer to?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

> Things come into being, exist and cease to exist, not each independent
> of all other things, but each in its relationship with other things.
> The very nature of a thing is modified and transformed by its
> relationships with other things. When things enter into such
> relationships that they become parts of a whole, the whole cannot be
> regarded as nothing more than the sum total of the parts. True, the
> whole is nothing apart from and independent of its parts. But the
> mutual relations which the parts enter into in constituting the whole
> modify **their own properties**, so that while it may be said that the
> whole is determined by the parts it may equally be said that the parts
> are determined by the whole.

[Materialism and the Dialectical Method - Maurice Cornforth]

What does "their own properties" refer to? "the mutual relations" or "the parts"

Comment: Which do you think is more likely? Why?

Comment: I think the mutual relations...